# Form datetime type validation error

Tags: symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I'm using collection form type, where children has datetime type input as single text. But when I submit data in validation fails and getErrorsAsString shows this strange error:

```
inputDateTime:
        ERROR: This value is not valid.
        date:
            No errors
        time:
            No errors
```

Here is how I add my field

```
//form child
$builder->add('inputDateTime', 'datetime', array(
    'date_widget' => 'single_text',
    'time_widget' => 'single_text'
));
```

Why inputDateTime has errors but neither date or time has errors? My locale is set and I tried to add date format but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

The ["error_bubbling" property of the "date" and the "time" field](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateTimeType.php#L146) is set to `true`, thus errors on those fields bubble up and are attached to the datetime field instead.

You are right that the error message is not very helpful (there's an [open ticket for that](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5946)) but you can debug the problem by printing the `$exception` variable in the [block that catches the `TransformationFailedException`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php#L611) generated by the DataTransformer (Form.php:611). The exception contains the detailed error description, which is hidden from the end user for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it appears that is due to an invalid format date (when you are using a different format which can appears when you have set another timezone or locale for instance). As a result, you juste have to specify the date_format options for the datetime field.

In my case, this solve the issue :

```
'date_format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
```